# how can I pop an input box for a specific choice?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In jenkins I'd like to do this:

```
parameters {
    choice(
            name: 'blah',
            choices: 'one\ntwo\ncustom',
            description: 'if you choose custom enter a custom number'
    )
}
```

So they have three options on the drop down, but it would be nice if when they select the "custom" choice jenkins pops an input box to type in raw user input.

Is this possible? I don't want to use user input during the pipeline run because that means they need to choose custom then wait for jenkins to get to the stage where it asks them for input.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, Once the build starts, check the value of params.blah and throw up an input step with a String param, so

```
if (params.blah == 'custom' ) {
    timeout(time: 1, unit: 'minute') { // change to a convenient timeout for you
        userInput = input(
        id: 'Proceed1', message: 'Custom value?', parameters: [
        [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', defaultValue: '', 
          description: 'Enter Custom value', name: 'Value']
        ])
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I want to avoid, they have to build, then sit and wait for a prompt

Comment: params are post-processed so they can't be dynamic on the page, alternative would be to have a String param in addition to the Dropdown, only use the String param value if "Custom" has been selected in the dropdown.